# Spring Security how to catch exception in PRE_AUTH_FILTER using exceptionMappings

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC (3.1.1.RELEASE) and Spring Security (3.1.0.RELEASE).

The spring application is a REST API server, handing over Json.

my security-context.xml contains this PRE_AUTH_FILTER filter :

```
<custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"  ref="siteminderFilter"  />
...
<beans:bean id="siteminderFilter" class=
"com.test.server.util.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter" >
    <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="login"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />    
</beans:bean>
```

my custom RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends **AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter**   and throws a **PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException**

So the users receives a 500 Internal Server Error.
But I would like the user to receive a JSON string instead. Is it possible ? if yes, how can I do that ?

I tried using exceptionMappings this way but it doesnt seem to work

```
<beans:bean id="siteminderFilter" class=
"com.pecunia.server.util.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter" >
    <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="login"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />    
   <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
      <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException">/error.json</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

gives me this error when deploying :

```
Bean property 'exceptionMappings' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter
```

I also tried

```
<form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
...
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
   <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
      <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException">/error.json</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

But no errors and no results (just the usual 500 page)

Comment: I'm also having same issue, did you find any solution? If yes, Please post answer